# Using SoapUI with Axis2 work ok and java code no work

Tags: apache-axis, soapui

the soupui requeset is working ok, but when I try the java code no work, I really confused by the issuse.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:port="http://service.composit.unic.capsa.com/UNICService/port" xmlns:sch="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema">
<soapenv:Header><wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><wsse:UsernameToken><wsse:Username>mdmadmin</wsse:Username><wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">mdmadmin</wsse:Password></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security></soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
<port:checkHeartBeatInfo>
<sch:RequestControl>
<sch:requestID>112</sch:requestID>
<sch:DWLControl>
<sch:requesterName>111</sch:requesterName>
<sch:requesterLanguage>100</sch:requesterLanguage>
<sch:clientSystemName>DCS_test</sch:clientSystemName>
</sch:DWLControl>
</sch:RequestControl>
<sch:InputCheckHeartBeatInfoBObj/>
</port:checkHeartBeatInfo>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <port:checkHeartBeatInfoResponse xmlns:port="http://service.composit.unic.capsa.com/UNICService/port">
         <ResponseControl xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema">
            <ResultCode>SUCCESS</ResultCode>
            <ServiceTime>58</ServiceTime>
            <DWLControl>
               <requesterName>mdmadmin</requesterName>
               <requesterLanguage>100</requesterLanguage>
               <requesterLocale>en</requesterLocale>
               <clientSystemName>DCS_test</clientSystemName>
               <userRole>mdm_admin</userRole>
               <requestID>112</requestID>
            </DWLControl>
         </ResponseControl>
         <TxResult xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema">
            <ResultCode>SUCCESS</ResultCode>
         </TxResult>
         <OutputCheckHeartBeatInfoBObj xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema">
            <ComponentID>2000172</ComponentID>
            <Rtn_code>Success!</Rtn_code>
         </OutputCheckHeartBeatInfoBObj>
      </port:checkHeartBeatInfoResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

my client test code is follow:

```
UNICServiceServiceStub stub = new UNICServiceServiceStub();

            CheckHeartBeatInfoDocument checkHeartBeatInfo18 = CheckHeartBeatInfoDocument.Factory.newInstance();
            CheckHeartBeatInfoInputType checkHeartBeatInfo = CheckHeartBeatInfoInputType.Factory.newInstance();

            DWLControl oDWLContorl = DWLControl.Factory.newInstance();
            oDWLContorl.setRequesterLanguage("100");
            oDWLContorl.setRequesterName("111");
            oDWLContorl.setClientSystemName("DCS_test");
            RequestControl requestControl = RequestControl.Factory.newInstance();
            requestControl.setRequestID("112");
            requestControl.setDWLControl(oDWLContorl);

            checkHeartBeatInfo.setRequestControl(requestControl);

            OMFactory omFactory = OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory();

            OMNamespace namespaceWSSE = omFactory.createOMNamespace("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", "wsse");
            OMElement header = omFactory.createOMElement("Security", namespaceWSSE);

            OMAttribute attribute = omFactory.createOMAttribute("soapenv:mustUnderstand", null, "1");
            header.addAttribute(attribute);

            OMElement omusertoken = omFactory.createOMElement("UsernameToken", namespaceWSSE);
            header.addChild(omusertoken);

            OMElement omuserName = omFactory.createOMElement("Username", namespaceWSSE);
            omuserName.setText("mdmadmin");

            OMElement omPassword = omFactory.createOMElement("Password", namespaceWSSE);
            omPassword.addAttribute("Type","http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText", null );
            omPassword.setText("mdmadmin");
            omusertoken.addChild(omuserName);
            omusertoken.addChild(omPassword);
            stub._getServiceClient().addHeader(header);
            checkHeartBeatInfo18.setCheckHeartBeatInfo(checkHeartBeatInfo);
            CheckHeartBeatInfoResponseDocument response = CheckHeartBeatInfoResponseDocument.Factory.newInstance();
            response = stub.checkHeartBeatInfo(checkHeartBeatInfo18);
            System.out.println(response.toString());
```

*I don't know why it throw exception? appreciate your help, thanks.*

Comment: Which exception? Stacktrace please.

Answer (score 0):

I solved. The key to done is comparing the xml of your code genarate with the soapui's.
public class Test
{

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        UNICServiceServiceStub stub = new UNICServiceServiceStub();

        DWLControl oDWLContorl = DWLControl.Factory.newInstance();
        oDWLContorl.setRequesterLanguage("100");
        oDWLContorl.setRequesterName("111");
        oDWLContorl.setClientSystemName("DCS_test");

        RequestControl requestControl = RequestControl.Factory.newInstance();
        requestControl.setRequestID("112");
        requestControl.setDWLControl(oDWLContorl);

        SOAPFactory omFactory = OMAbstractFactory.getSOAP11Factory();

        OMNamespace namespaceWSSE = omFactory.createOMNamespace("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", "wsse");
        OMElement omSecurityElement = omFactory.createOMElement("Security", namespaceWSSE);
        OMAttribute attribute = omFactory.createOMAttribute("soapenv:mustUnderstand", null, "1");
        omSecurityElement.addAttribute(attribute);

        OMElement omusertoken = omFactory.createOMElement("UsernameToken", namespaceWSSE);


        OMElement omuserName = omFactory.createOMElement("Username", namespaceWSSE);
        omuserName.setText("mdmadmin");

        OMElement omPassword = omFactory.createOMElement("Password", namespaceWSSE);
        omPassword.addAttribute("Type","http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText", null );
        omPassword.setText("mdmadmin");

        omusertoken.addChild(omuserName);
        omusertoken.addChild(omPassword);
        omSecurityElement.addChild(omusertoken);

        InputCheckHeartBeatInfoBObjType inputCheckHeartBeatInfoBObj = InputCheckHeartBeatInfoBObjType.Factory.newInstance();
        CheckHeartBeatInfoDocument checkHeartBeatInfo18 = CheckHeartBeatInfoDocument.Factory.newInstance();
        CheckHeartBeatInfoInputType checkHeartBeatInfo = CheckHeartBeatInfoInputType.Factory.newInstance();
        checkHeartBeatInfo.setRequestControl(requestControl);
        checkHeartBeatInfo.setInputCheckHeartBeatInfoBObj(inputCheckHeartBeatInfoBObj);

        checkHeartBeatInfo18.setCheckHeartBeatInfo(checkHeartBeatInfo);

        stub._getServiceClient().addHeader(omSecurityElement);

        CheckHeartBeatInfoResponseDocument response = stub.checkHeartBeatInfo(checkHeartBeatInfo18);
        System.out.println(response.toString());


    }
    catch (AxisFault e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (RemoteException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ProcessingFault e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}